# why extension methods in C# Class Libraries

Tags: c#, extension-methods, class-library

I did go through some [MSDN documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412719.aspx). I found extension methods also documented there.

I didn't understand, why these base class libraries have extension methods? when they could have been added to that particular class library itself?

what is the advantage? difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension methods as name suggests extends the functionality or usability of the target type.

1. These methods can be added later (than type authoring time) after type has already been published.
2. They can be written by different group of people
3. Extension methods can target interfaces. (Alternative would have been to have a common base type having these methods or re-implementing them in each type)
4. Different people can extend the same type differently as per their needs.

Correct use of extension methods can remove orthogonal clutter from the actual type definition/implementation (instead focusing of the core functionality of the type within type definition).

Take example of LINQ - by providing extension methods to `IEnumerable`, it could target vast number of already published types (and vast number of types that may written in future); it has separated orthogonal concern such as querying the type from the actual type.

Comment: Item #3 on your list is completely wrong.  It completely misrepresents the mechanics of extension methods as described in your 'alternative'.  Also, what do you mean by "querying the type from the actual type"?

Comment: @A.R., perhaps u need to explain a bit what is *wrong* in #3. Good example for #3 is `IEnumerable<T>` - if interface could not be target by extensions methods then some-body would have to write implementation for all those methods in specific types (or their common base type).

Comment: @A.R., further, I had used the term "orthogonal concern such as querying the type from the actual type" in the context of `IEnumerable` - it simply means that different collections such as dictionary, list, queue, set, stack etc doesn't have to provide implementation for various querying methods (join, count, first, last etc). This logic is really not the core concern for those classes.

Comment: The actual alternative is to write a static method that takes an 'IEnumeralbe<T>' instance as an argument.  This is EXACTLY what extension methods do when they are compiled.  Suggesting that some 'base class' would have to 're-implement' what amounts to a helper function is both absurd and dangerously misleading.  Take the extension method 'Max' for example and use it in your suggested 'alternative'.  At what point exactly do I need to re-implement it?

Comment: Your last point about LINQ, and explanation for it makes no sense.  You are suggesting that extension methods are "providing implementation" on those collection types, and that IS NOT what extension methods do.

Comment: @A.R., static helper methods could have been written since .NET 1.0. The very idea of extension methods is that they appears to be part of (member of) type! so for `Max` method to be a part of `IEnumerable<T>` interface, every interface implementation would have to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

Note, that many of the these methods operates on Interfaces, which is a perfectly legitimate excuse of using Extension Methods, even for Microsoft since interfaces themselves can't have any implementation of methods.

Answer (score 1):

The extension methods documented are defined on `IEnumerable<T>`, which `ObjectSet<T>` implements.

They are documented so you know you can use them.

As extension methods they end up extending *any* type implementing this interface, for free.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's most probbably a "marketing issue". The way to advise  to `BCL` consumer (us) to use Extension methods, where we need them.

From the usability perspective, there is *no any goodness*, imo, of integrating them in `BCL`